# Init an object, then store it into an NSArray. Is this going to be a leak?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, memory-management

If an inited object comes to me retained, so I own it, and I store it in an NSArray, which retains that which gets stored in it, can I count on NSArray to see that it's already retained and not increase the count, or do I need to run through the array and decrement the retain count to insure no memory leak?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make sure that the ownership of the object which was added into the `NSArray` is relinquished, send the `-release` message to the object right after you add it to the `NSArray`. If you do not do this, then you will indeed have a memory leak.

This is what happens:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", @"Blah"]; //retain count is 1, you own this object
[array addObject:str]; //retain count gets bumped to 2
[str release]; //retain count is 1 - relinquishing ownership here.
//There is no leak because when the NSArray is
//deallocated, the object will be sent the release message.
```

But if you *don't* send the owned inserted object the `-release` message, then even when the `NSArray` is deallocated, the object will only have  a retain count of `1` and the memory obtained by the object will never be reclaimed, thereby resulting in a leak.

Comment: This is not a particularly good example since literal strings have UINT_MAX retain count.

Comment: `-initWithString:literal` also yields an object with UINT_MAX retain count. `-initWithFormat:` is a better choice for your example. Literal strings are tricky with regard to retain counts, heh.

Comment: So a good way to think about collections is that you and the collection have joint custody of the object, and it doesn't go away until both of you release it.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you need to read the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html). Your case is extremely simple. You own the object. You pass it to the array, which now also owns it. You need to release your ownership of it. Otherwise you'll leak it.

Comment: +1 *This* is the correct answer.  `retainCount` has nothing to do with what's going on, and thinking about things in terms of the retain count is not a good idea.  Think instead about whether you own the object or not.

Comment: @Dave, the precise problem I had was whether a collection takes ownership of a stored object, or adds to it.

Comment: @Hack Saw ["In a managed memory environment, an object receives a retain message when it’s added; in a garbage collected environment, it is strongly referenced. When an array is deallocated in a managed memory environment, each element is sent a release message."](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-SW1)

Comment: @Dave: that still doesn't answer my question. A release message doesn't get rid of an object, it just decrements its retain count. If it's higher than 0, it sticks around.

Comment: @Hack Saw: It absolutely answers your question. You should *never* think of whether or not an object is dealloc'd, think purely in terms of ownership. Objects added to the array are owned by the array. When the array is dealloc'd, it releases ownership on all objects contained in it. That's really all you need to know.

Comment: @Kevin: The quote above doesn't clearly define ownership. Neither does the Memory Management guide, though it does provide an invaluable example of the special case of collections, so thank you for reminding me about that. The important idea here is that ownership is defined as "having retained the item", and more importantly when an Collection "takes ownership", it's not doing anything other than sending it a retain message. For instance, it isn't taking ownership the way a human might take ownership of a car when buying it.

Comment: @Hack Saw from [The Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW1): "•You own any object you create. <snip>  •You can take ownership of an object using `retain`."  I don't mean to be an "RTFM" guy, but this question comes up quite frequently and the documentation *does* explain what's going on. (granted, the MMPG was updated very recently...)

Comment: Again, it's about the definition of ownership. You have to dig deep to grok that ownership isn't really ownership. Because it's not. You only truly own an object if you are the *only* controller. In the case of a collection, it adds to the retain count, meaning both you and the collection "own" it. The problem isn't whether TFM says what you should do, it's whether it's quick and clear. Yes, if I had read every page of the memory management guide, I would find this out. Like a lot of people, I'm tight for time, so I read enough to get me by.

Comment: The key information here isn't "you own something you get by init, copy or which you retain." The key information is "a collection ups the retain count when it stores an item, and releases it when it's done with it, *and nothing else*. If you 'owned' it before, you still do." That statement, in that manner, would help people's understanding.

Comment: @Hack Saw: "You only truly own an object if you are the only controller" <- What makes you say that? An object can have multiple owners. *Stop thinking about retain count*. There's a very good reason the MMPG was rewritten to talk about object ownership. Retain count is a terrible way to think about object lifetime, it confuses people and causes subtle bugs. Object ownership is incredibly simple, and works.

Comment: Because the MMPG starts the article on Collections with: "When you add an object to a collection such as an array, dictionary, or set, the collection takes ownership of it." and then goes and contradicts the meaning of the word ownership. The proper analogy is the machine power lockouts which people use to prevent others from powering on a machine before they are ready. This is hard, because you need to spend time explaining it, but ownership most people understand to be 100% complete control of the thing, so it's confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you release the NSArray, it'll release everything it retains.

As such, as long as you release the inited object once you've added it to the NSArray (so it's the only thing that retains it) or release it once you've finished with it outside of the array all should be fine.

Incidentally, there's a good blog post called "[objective-c memory management for lazy people](http://interfacelab.com/objective-c-memory-management-for-lazy-people/)" that explains such things pretty well and is a handy reference if you're just starting out with such things.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do that. `NSArray` takes ownership of any object that it stores. It will release its objects when it's deallocated. If you retain an object yourself, you take ownership too, and you are responsible for releasing it too.

Answer (score 0):

NSArray *will* retain your object when you add it, and then release it when you remove it from the array. This is by design. This means that to ensure there's no memory leak, if you already retained the object before adding it to the array, you should release it after removing it from the array:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
NSObject *object = [[NSObject alloc] init]; // retain count of 1 (because of alloc)
[object retain]; // useless, just for example, retain count of 2 (because of retain)
[array addObject:object]; // array is mutable, retain count of 3 (because of addObject:)
[array removeObject:object]; // retain count of 2
[object release]; // retain count of 1
[object release]; // retain count of 0, the object is dealloc'd afterwards
[array release]; // to be sure that we are not leaking an array, too
```